# Shared Mac Pro Server - how to login without needing password?

Tags: networking, macos, mac, remote-desktop, vnc

I have a Mac Pro, running OS X Yosemite, as a "server" for hosting my backups and file sharing within a personal network. What I would like to do is have a way for users to access this computer **without** needing to put in a username/password. I understand the security risks and I also understand I could do this with an airdrop or public folder, but it maintains multiple HDDs and a complex directory structure I am hoping to keep intact.

Currently there are two way users log onto this computer:

- **Via finder** - the computer has file sharing on, and it appears to users in their shared or networked computers

*With this method, users are asked to sign in as a registered user, guest or using an Apple ID - I would like them to be able to log in as a guest and have full rights to all volumes and subsequent folders*

- **with a VNC client** - using something like [chicken](https://sourceforge.net/projects/chicken/), users are able to remotely login to the "server" and do various needed tasks

*When logging in with the VNC client users are presented with the mac login screen (see screenshot below) - if possible, I would like users to bypass this login screen.*

Any help would be appreciated, I am not sure if it is even possible, but after exhausting all attempts of changing settings I figure this would deb my best bet for find help.

[image: mac pro - vnc login]

Answer (score 2):

this is the command to write in a terminal window:

sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.RemoteManagement VNCAlwaysStartOnConsole -bool true

Answer (score 1):

I don't think using a VNC client is the best or easiest option for file-sharing, since that's mainly for screens-sharing & remote control.

Anyway, based on the info I read from [this site](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/set-chicken-vnc-remote-access-mac/) (I don't use a Mac), you could go to **System Preferences > Sharing** then click on **Options** and enable the checkbox **"Anyone may request permission to control screen"** instead of the last checkbox that requires a password.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply, unfortunately that setting then disallows the use of a VNC client.

Comment: I have EXACTLY the same problem and question, would be great if someone could give an valid answer. I have even tried to disable the system login (enable automatic login) but this action doesnt disable the login for the vnc.